# How to rename files with sequential even and odd numbers in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, rename-item-cmdlet

I would like to know how I can rename the files from a specific folder with a sequence of only even and odds numbers in PowerShell. E.g. Folder1: `pag_001.jpg, pag_003.jpg, pag_005.jpg.... pag_201.jpg` , Folder2: `pag_002.jpg, pag_004.jpg, pag_006.jpg.... pag_200.jpg`. It is because I have a document that was scanned first the odds pages and secondly the even pages, therefore their file names are in a consecutive sequence from 1 to 201. Then I separated one half of the files which are the odds pages in a new place: `Folder1`, and the second half,the even pages in the `Folder2`. That is why I would like change the names first and the join again together with their new names.

I have tried this based in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304025/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-powershell-with-sequential-numeric-suffixes):

At the moment I could generate even number sequences like that:

```
ForEach ($number in 1..100 ) { $number * 2}
```

and odd numbers like that:

```
ForEach ($number in 0..100 ) { $number *2+1}
```

and wanted apply the sequences generated before to rename my files like that:

```
cd C:\test\Folder1
$i = $number * 2
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('pag_{0:D3}.jpg' -f $i++)}
```

but it doesn't works!  Any suggestions are welcome

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$i++` adds `1` each time, this is why it also add even numbers,

You can create array of Odd Numbers then use the `$i++` to step one item in the array, like this:

```
$path = "C:\test\Folder1"
$oddNumbersArray = 0..100 | % {$_ *2 +1}
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.jpg | % {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("pag_$($oddNumbersArray[$i]).jpg") ;$i++}
```

For Even Numbers change the `$oddNumbersArray` line to `{$_ *2}`

Comment: using `-f` operator inside the expression is a bit ambiguous, since you don't actually substitute any placeholders in the string. Why not just move `$i++` outside the `Rename-Item` operation?

Answer (score 1):

Bunch of ways to do this. For mine we add each index as a member so that it is more easily accessible in the rename item script block.

```psh
$index = 0 

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.jpg" | ForEach-Object{
    $index = $index +2
    $_ | Add-Member -Name "Index" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $index -PassThru
} | Rename-Item -NewName {'pag_{0:D3}.jpg' -f $_.Index} -WhatIf
```

Using `Add-Member` in a `ForEach-Object` we update the value of index and then add it as a property of the same name. Then in your `rename-item` scriptblock we can call that property. Remove the `-WhatIf` after you verified the new names are what you wanted. Switch `$index` between 0 and -1 for even and odd respectively.

---

Another method using a global index variable and mitigating the pipeline by using calculated properties to create the pipeline variables that `Rename-Item` uses.

```
$path = "C:\Temp\csv"
$global:index = 0 # Use -1 for odd

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.csv" | 
    Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.FullName}},
        @{Name="NewName";Expression={$global:index = $global:index + 2; 'pag_{0:D3}.jpg' -f $global:index}} | 
    Rename-Item  -WhatIf
```

Comment: I feel bad since I know it can be more verbose than this. So I will try to update it.